# PHP array error: Indirect modification of overloaded property

Tags: php, smarty

Why is this line of code:

```
$this->plugins_dir[0] = SMARTY_DIR . 'plugins';
```

causing this error?

```
ERRNO: 8
TEXT: Indirect modification of overloaded property Page::$plugins_dir has no effect
```

By the way, the line of code is inside the constructor of a class named 'Page'.

I am working with PHP and PostgreSQL, but am not too experienced. I am stuck
with this problem for few hours now, can't find the reason.

Comment: Which version of Smarty are you using?

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/q/10454779/1190388 ?

Comment: brbcoding: I use Smarty-3.1.13

Answer (score 8):

What PHP is trying to tell you is that the property `->plugins_dir` doesn't really exist, but a magic `__get()` function has been written that will return a value if you read from it. Assigning a variable directly to it might also work (if there is a corresponding `__set()`) but you cannot *modify* it, since it is actually a function return value. You are effectively trying to say `$this->__get('plugins_dir')[0] = 'foo'`, which doesn't mean anything.

However, looking at [the relevant Smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.plugins.dir.tpl), we can see what the correct solution is:

> **Note**: As of Smarty 3.1 the attribute $plugins_dir is no longer accessible directly. Use getPluginsDir(), setPluginsDir() and addPluginsDir() instead.

So your code should actually use the pattern of one of the examples on [the doc page for addPluginsDir()](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.add.plugins.dir.tpl), such as:

```
$this->setPluginsDir( SMARTY_DIR . 'plugins' )
     ->addPluginsDir( '/some/other/source/of/plugins' );
```

Comment: I'm using the Laravel framework and this was an excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right way

```
$this->plugins_dir = SMARTY_DIR . 'plugins';
```

Comment: it must be some modified version of smarty then.