# Unset validate rules in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I want unset validate rules in beforValidate but I have notices:

```
Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property User::$validate has no effect
```

My code:

```
function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    if (empty($this->data[$this->name]['name']) && empty($this->data[$this->name]['name2'])) {
        unset(
                $this->validate['name'], $this->validate['name2']
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

How can I unset rules without notices?

Comment: There's something wrong with your model, you'll only receive such a message in case there is no `$validate` property. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19716393/1392379 ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 7):

First step is to usually try the [Amazing Online CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html).

If you do that, you'll notice there's a section on how to [remove validation rules](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#removing-rules-from-the-set).