# Create filter for CGridView

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I have a module, that have one Controller, one set of view, and 5 models(in future can be more). 
So in controller i have action

```
    $model = new $modelName('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes(); 
    $model->create_user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;

    if (isset($_GET[$modelName]))
        $model->attributes = $_GET[$modelName];

    $this->render('model_view/adminModel', array(
        'modelName' => $modelName,
        'model'     => $model,
        ));
```

and in view i have a widget based on CGridView

```
    $this->widget('application.components.widgets.usertheme.UserGridView', 
    array(
        'id'=>'user-grid',
        'dataProvider'  =>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'       => .....
.....
        )
    );
```

If i put in action action (line #3)

> $model->create_user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;

it works fine, and show the data that are created by user that is on system now. 
But if i want to find inforamtion from this table, but with the filter  - created document by USER from another table (i have relation with it)

> 'document' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Document', 'document_id'),

and in action write

> $model->document->create_user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;

it doesnt work, and give error

> Indirect modification of overloaded property Reports::$document has no effect

Comment: probably this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454779/php-indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property

Comment: @Alejandro , thx, but this doesn help. I found one workaround better for me)/