# Random data container using magic methods __get and __set

Tags: php, containers, magic-methods

Is it possible to create a PHP class that can hold whatever type of data you throw at it, even recursively, using magic methods?

I saw this: [PHP - Indirect modification of overloaded property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454779/php-indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property/10455217#10455217)

but it doesn't handle recursive data:

```
class ActiveRecord extends Creator {

}

$a = new ActiveRecord();

$a->_id = "123456789";
$a->persona_info = [
    "name" => "Bob",
    "surnames" => ["First", "Second", "Third"]
];
$a->history = [
    "logins" => [
        [
            "date" => "1999",
            "ip" => "1.2.3.4"
        ],
        [
            "date" => "1129",
            "ip" => "1.2.3.4"
        ]
    ],
    "purchases" => [
        [
            "date" => "1819",
            "amount" => "1884"
        ],
        [
            "date" => "1459",
            "amount" => "14"
        ]
    ]
];

var_dump($a->history->logins);
```

That gives me:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /tmp/x.php on line 90
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/x.php:0
NULL
```

Trying to investigate further, I see that `$a->history` is a plain php array instead of a `Value` object (or even a `Creator` object.

Comment: You should post the `Creator` class as well

Comment: @DarkBee It's in the link in my question.

Comment: Dont think most people tend to click through. I did not at first read, anyway you are using the modified version of the `creator` class?

Comment: You need to return another object that also has magic methods, not the raw array.

Comment: @Barmar Where should that be? In the `__get` method of `Value`?

Comment: Possibly, I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: At first glance i'm not sure you can convert the `login` key to a `StdClass`, because how would you retrieve the values in it? A property name can't start with a numeric value. You will need to alter the `__get` method and create a class that is able to retrieve these value for instance with the interface `ArrayAccess`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is `$a->history` is an `array` and not a `object`. It should be `var_dump($a->history['logins']);`

Comment: Yes, that would work for this specific case, but my question is more broad. I'm trying to access values using `->`,  which means that each value should be an object, which then should contain all children values, etc.

Comment: That's the problem. If you want it to be a object then you need to declare it differently and not like that.

Comment: OP is using magic methods to modify passed data, in this case convert array to `StdClass`, see linked answer