# Laravel setPublishedAtAttribute error

Tags: php, laravel

can someone help me with this error?

Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Article::$atributes has no effect

Here's the code:

```
public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date){
    $this->atributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
}
```

I am trying to add clock to my published_at column...

Comment: Please take a look at this question for some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454779/php-indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I've fount the problem a few minutes after I've posted this question...

```
$this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
```

I've missed one "t" letter in Attributes. :)