# Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property LayoutHelper::$View has no effect [APP/View/Helper/LayoutHelper.php, line 48]

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

While migrating CakePHP code from 1.3 to 2.x I am getting this notice message:-

> Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property LayoutHelper::$View has no effect [APP/View/Helper/LayoutHelper.php, line 48]

The code for this notice is:-

```
function __construct($options = array()) {
    $this->View =& ClassRegistry::getObject('view');
    $this->__loadHooks();

    return parent::__construct($options);
}
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: "*What should I do to fix this?*" - Start using the search function? This has been asked a few thousand times. Just search for the error message. It is unlikely you're the first person to encounter it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Indirect modification of overloaded property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454779/php-indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property)

Comment: @burzum not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

### Understanding the notice

The message means that a property is being set which is accessed with a magic accessor - it's not going to actually do anything. It is equivalent to this:

```
<?php

class Foo {
        function __get($prop) {
            return [];
        }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar['zum'] = "x";
print_r($foo->bar); // []
```

In this contrived example the property "bar" does not exist, and so the magic getter is called returning an empty array - the code is attempting to append/write to this magic-getter-returned-value and emits the same notice:

> Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Foo::$bar has no effect in /tmp/overload-example.php on line 12

As shown by the `print_r` call, the value of `$foo->bar` has not changed.

The normal solution is to declare the property so that the magic getter is *not* used i.e.:

```
class Foo {
    public $bar = []; // Now it can be modified.
```

However in this case that's *not* the most appropriate thing to do.

### Helpers changed from 1.x to 2.x

The constructor for all helpers changed in 2.x which is [in the migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#constructor-changed). Read the migration guide in detail, especially if you encounter a problem.

In 1.3 all helpers extend [the helper class](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3.0/cake/libs/view/helper.php), it doesn't have a constructor, and does not keep a reference to the view. In 2.x all helpers extend the same class but [do have a constructor and do keep a reference to the view class](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.0/lib/Cake/View/Helper.php#L212-L213). There are 2 steps related to this error to upgrade the helper to be 2.x compatible

#### Change the constructor:

There is no need to repeat logic the parent constructor is doing for you so just call `__loadHooks` (if necessary):

```
function __construct(View $View, $settings = array()) {
    $this->__loadHooks();
    return parent::__construct($View, $settings);
}
```

#### Change references to `$this->View`

All helpers [have access to the view instance](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.0/lib/Cake/View/Helper.php#L100-L105), just find and replace in your helper code replacing this:

```
$this->_View
```

With this:

```
$this->View
```